# raw SELECT query work but not with variables plugged in PHP code

Tags: php, mysql

My raw SELECT query work but not with variables plugged in in PHP code.

Here is my actual select query:

```
SELECT * FROM `program_list`
WHERE
speciality LIKE '%IM%'
AND (stepone2digit <= 78 OR stepone2digit=0)
AND (stepone3digit <= 189 OR stepone3digit=0)
AND (steptwock2digit <= 78 OR steptwock2digit=0)
AND (steptwock3digit <= 189 OR steptwock3digit=0)
AND (steptwocs = 'PASS' OR steptwocs IS NULL)
AND (steponeattempt <= 1 OR steponeattempt=0)
AND (steptwockattempt <= 1 OR steptwockattempt=0)
AND (steptwocsattempt <= 2 OR steptwocsattempt=0)
AND ((USCEImportance = 'MAND' AND USCENoOfMonths<= '3') OR USCEImportance = 'PREF')
AND (yearsfrompassing >= 2 OR yearsfrompassing=0);
```

Here is how I am passing it in PHP:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `program_list`
    WHERE
    speciality LIKE '%%s%'
    AND (stepone2digit <= %d OR stepone2digit=0)
    AND (stepone3digit <= %d OR stepone3digit=0)
    AND (steptwock2digit <= %d OR steptwock2digit=0)
    AND (steptwock3digit <= %d OR steptwock3digit=0)
    AND (steptwocs = '%s' OR steptwocs IS NULL)
    AND (steponeattempt <= %d OR steponeattempt=0)
    AND (steptwockattempt <= %d OR steptwockattempt=0)
    AND (steptwocsattempt <= %d OR steptwocsattempt=0)
    AND ((USCEImportance = 'MAND' AND USCENoOfMonths<= '%s') OR USCEImportance = 'PREF')
    AND (yearsfrompassing >= %d OR yearsfrompassing=0)
```

When I run the raw query it works fine but when I plug the variables in and run it from PHP no results are returned.

What am I missing? Please help.

Comment: Where/how are you converting the %d's to numbers?

Comment: have you tried to debug using echo $sql?

Comment: Use `sprintf` to replace your `%s` and `%d` with real values.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't assign the '%d' and '%s' there (try to debug your $sql using var_dump($sql)). You should use sprintf for this. For example :

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `program_list` WHERE speciality LIKE '%%s%'",$speciality);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using `sprintf` to replace your %s and %d with real values.

The problem is on this code fragment:

```
speciality LIKE '%%s%'
```

`%%` will be replaced by a single `%`, and the last `%` will return a warning or notice because `%'` is not valid for `sprintf`. You must use that syntax instead:

```
speciality LIKE '%%%s%%'
```

Your full query would be:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `program_list`
WHERE
speciality LIKE '%%%s%%'
AND (stepone2digit <= %d OR stepone2digit=0)
AND (stepone3digit <= %d OR stepone3digit=0)
AND (steptwock2digit <= %d OR steptwock2digit=0)
AND (steptwock3digit <= %d OR steptwock3digit=0)
AND (steptwocs = '%s' OR steptwocs IS NULL)
AND (steponeattempt <= %d OR steponeattempt=0)
AND (steptwockattempt <= %d OR steptwockattempt=0)
AND (steptwocsattempt <= %d OR steptwocsattempt=0)
AND ((USCEImportance = 'MAND' AND USCENoOfMonths<= '%s') OR USCEImportance = 'PREF')
AND (yearsfrompassing >= %d OR yearsfrompassing=0)";
```

And don't forget to use `sprintf` to insert the values in your query.